# How to flash an RPI board wirelessly?

Tags: raspberry-pi-pico

How can I achieve wireless flash of an RPI Pico W board?

I need this because during testing of my device, I will need to tune it and flash the board frequently which will save time rather then connecting it to my PC all the time.